# Linkbutton OnClick won't fire If I add datatoggle for modal

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net

I have a linkbutton inside a repeater, I want it to pop a modal and execute a function in CodeBehind to get a list from Database but all it does is pop the modal and ignores the OnClick event...

```
<asp:LinkButton 
    runat="server" 
    ID="lkbtnDetalhes" 
    data-toggle="modal" 
    data-target=".bs-example-modal-lg" 
    AutoPostBack="false" 
    OnClick="DetalhesRequisicao">

    <%# Eval("RefCliente")%>

</asp:LinkButton>
```

Comment: That is how it should be. Otherwise a PostBack or navigate away will happen and you lose the Modal anyway. The modal code adds a return false or something similair to the anchor.

Comment: How can I execute a function and open the model at the same time then?

Comment: You don't. Not without editing the plugin that generates the modal.

Comment: You can try having the modal openned from the codebehind along with all the stuff you want to happen. Although, what’ll happen is that the modal will only open after the other stuff is finished.